# Request: Please create the "Per-Site Community Promotion Ads" post

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, site-promotion

[Today, on the SE blog, per-site community promotions ads were announced.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/)

I haven't found a post related to them on this meta yet, and the blog post said:

> (If your site does not yet have a
>   community promotion post on its meta,
>   contact me to request one, or simply
>   post a meta request asking for it to
>   be created.)

Consider that requested!